# A major incident was declared

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

***A major incident was declared*** when winds caused two fires to merge near communication masts on Saturday.

From BBC.com

How should we interpret the main clause that a major incident was declared? Does it mean when winds caused fires and at that time somebody declared an incident or the major incident here is exactly the fire incident?

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-lancashire-44676707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the procedure of the Fire Brigade.

A small fire will be put out by the local fire brigade. But if the fire becomes more serious the local fire chief will decide to call it a "major incident" and get external help and support.

In this case, there were two small fires. The winds changed and the two small fires joined up to become one large fire. This fire was near some "communication masts". The local fire chief realised that his firefighters couldn't put out the fire alone, so he called the fire a "major incident" and got help from other firefighters.

As the reporter doesn't know who the fire chief is, the reporter uses the passive voice.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean when winds caused fires and at that time somebody declared an incident or the major incident here is exactly the fire incident?

The verb phrase "was declared" is passive voice, and passive voice is "designed" to avoid answering those questions directly.  You're supposed to infer or figure it out unless there is a *by X* following.

It makes the most sense for "winds causing two fires to merge near communication masts" to be the major incident, *but* - the actual "incident" is probably a major communication outage that lasts a while.  The fire is technically the cause of it.

Of course it's totally possible "two fires merging" is also technically the actual incident.

The passive voice allows the reader to infer and take on the same assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't the winds that caused the fires. It was the winds that caused two preexisting fires to merge.

The major incident was declared when the two fires *merged*. (And also because this happened next to communication masts "which are essentially part of critical national infrastructure.")

The inference is that each fire was not a major incident on its own, but the combined fire became so.